# How to use cyper queries of Neo4j in Java Application

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using CypersQueries to create nodes  from java Applicaton. I am following the above link

```
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-create.html
```

In my javaApplication i used a sample query  as above

```
public class CretaeQuery
{
    public static final String DBPATH="D:/Neo4j/CQL";

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GraphDatabaseService path=new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(DBPATH);
        Transaction tx=path.beginTx();
        try
        {
        Map<String, Object> props  = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        props .put( "name", "Sharon" );
        props .put( "position", "Engineer" );

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put( "props", props  );

        ExecutionEngine engine=new ExecutionEngine(path);
        ExecutionResult result=engine.execute( "create ({props})", params );
        System.out.println(result);
        tx.success();
        } 
        finally
        {
             tx.finish();
             path.shutdown();

        }
    }
}
```

when I am running the above Class I am facing the above eror

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/concurrentlinkedhashmap/ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.LRUCache.<init>(LRUCache.scala:30)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anon$1.<init>(ExecutionEngine.scala:84)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.<init>(ExecutionEngine.scala:84)
    at com.neo4j.CretaeQuery.main(CretaeQuery.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap$Builder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

I have no idea why the error is throwing. please suggest me with proper code

Answer (score 1):

You are missing stuff in your classpath, or the server wasn't properly initialized. The concurrenthashmap was put in a about a month ago, as a jar in /lib. Is this in embedded mode or server mode?

Comment: Hi, Which jars I am missing in classpath. I am using neo4j-community-1.9-SNAPSHOT.zip in Windows 32 bit.

Comment: We found a problem last night in the packaging that is probably causing this by not being included as a dependency. In the meantime you can add the concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.1.jar to your classpath. Located in `neo4j-community-1.9-SNAPSHOT/system/lib/`.